# How do you insert multiple input at the same time in python?

Tags: python, c++

I had little experience with C++ and there is this function which I really like about it:

(this is a simple example for a calculator with only addition)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int a, b;
    cout << "insert numbers and calculations" << endl;
    cin >> a >> b;
    cout << a + b << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I really like the `cin` system since you can have multiple inputs at the same time. But on Python, I only one at the same time like this:

```
float a = 0
float b = 0
a = input("insert fist number")
b = input("insert the second number")
print(a + b)
```

I want to find a way to have multiple inputs at the same time similar to the `cin` syntax. What are the solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this way

```
a, b = [int(x) for x in input("Enter two values: ").split()] 
print("First Number is: ", a) 
print("Second Number is: ", b) 
print()
```

Comment: is there a way to use other types of variables at the same time, (e.g. strings)

Comment: you may want to change ```int(x)``` as ```str(x)``` or just leave the ```x``` as it is.

Answer (score 1):

### Input

As for multiple inputs at once, you can use:

`[input("Enter value {}: ".format(x + 1)) for x in range(2)]`

Which creates an array of two values base on the two inputs which will be asked this way:

```
Enter value 1: YOUR_VALUE
Enter value 2: YOUR_VALUE
```

Or if you want some fancy customized texts

```
texts = ["The first number: ", "And the second number: "]
x, y = [input(x) for x in texts]
```

Or you can use `input().split()` that will split based on spaces

```
x, y = input("Two values: ").split() # Enter '10 10'
```

Source: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/taking-multiple-inputs-from-user-in-python/

Comment: @BenjaminAnshin Yes if you follow the third method I gave based on spaces

Answer (score 1):

By using split() you can input multiple values at the same time.

```
a, b = input("Enter a two value: ").split() 
print("Value of a: ", a) 
print("Value of b: ", b)
```

Try this